# clear gdb screen in emacs?

Tags: emacs, gdb

As the title, how can I clear gdb command screen in Emacs.
I tried with **shell clear** but It only work with gdb in terminal.

Have anyone here give me an ideal?

Thank in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can clear the whole buffer by typing <kbd>C-x h C-w SPC RET</kbd>.

Comment: Thank for your reply. It works but when I press RET It means that I also run a new command that repeat the previous command.

Comment: Can be fixed by inserting a space character before RET. I've changed my answer accordingly.

Comment: Ok, It works fine now :), though It is quite long of combined keys

Answer (score 1):

You can bind this defun to a key of your choice:

```
(defun clean-comint-buffer()
  (interactive)
  (delete-region (point-min)
                 (save-excursion
                   (goto-char (point-max))
                   (forward-line 0)
                   (point))))
```

It works for gdb and other comint-based modes (shell, interactive sql, etc...) that sometimes tend to grow with lines no longer useful.

**EDIT**

For binding this function to all comint buffers (gdb buffer is one of those), you may use (assuming you want C-c g):

```
(add-hook 'comint-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (local-set-key "\C-cg" 'clean-comint-buffer)))
```

Comment: I have not much knowledge about config emacs, but I just an user. So, can you guide me mean to bind this a defun to a key? I did as bellow with expect that bind C-c g (clear gdb) but it didn't work. Maybe I made a fool. Can you help me?

;; ===== Clear gdb screen
(defun clean-comint-buffer ()
  (interactive)
  (delete-region (point-min)
                 (save-excursion
                   (goto-char (point-max))
                   (forward-line 0)
                   (point))))
  (local-set-key "\C-cg" 'clean-comint-buffer)

Comment: @dangnam2910, see mi edit for a way of binding this to that key

Answer (score 0):

Type <kbd>C-l C-l</kbd>. This will scroll the buffer so that the current line is at the top of the window.

Comment: I known that but when I run a new command It will scroll to the bottom again.